# Is it safe to throw exceptions from within C++ noexcept functions if you want to terminate the program?

Tags: c++, exception, noexcept

Passing an exception through a `noexcept` function is supposed to terminate the program.  My question is whether it is safe and reasonable practice to rely on this behavior in cases where you could have a program bug that leads the exception to be thrown.

A simple example would be when you want to call the same functions on both validated and unvalidated input, as in here:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

struct tree {};

tree
parse(char *p)
{
  if (*p)
    throw std::length_error("only 0-length arguments allowed");
  return {};
}

struct validated {
  char *buf_;
  validated(char *buf) : buf_(buf) { parse(buf_); }
};

tree
parse(const validated &v) noexcept
{
  return parse(v.buf_);
}
```

In the above code, I would like `parse(const validated &v)` to be `noexcept`.  Of course, there could be a bug in the code where I modify a buffer after it has already been validated.  In that case I would like the program to crash and dump core like an assertion failure, but I want to avoid the risk of undefined or otherwise exploitable behavior that could do worse than crash the program.

Comment: Yes, it is **safe** from a C++ language standpoint.  In the sense that it has well-defined, deterministic behavior.